# How to return the result of a Alamofire POST request from within a method without it being nil?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm making an app, with UIKit-Storyboard, that simulates a login screen:
The moment the user enters the login data (*username* and *password*) and then clicks the *login* button, a class responsible for encapsulating requests with Alamofire invokes a method whose return is the result of the POST request (I use in this project the Clean Swift Architecture, so in this case the Interactor delegates this function to a Worker and it returns an object).

My problem is that I need to use the return of this method (the result of the POST request) to display some data on the screen. However, since the requests with Alamofire are *asynchronous*, the function returns **nil** before the request fills the object.

My classes looks like this:

> #### **Class LoginInteractor** (where I expect the result of the request but always returns nil):

```
class LoginInteractor: LoginBusinessLogic {
    var httpRequestWorker: LoginHTTPRequestWorker!
            
    func applyBusinessLogic(request: Login.Login.Request) {
        let user = User(username: request.fields.username,
                        password: request.fields.password)
        // (1)
        if let userData = self.doLoginInEndpoint(with: user) {
            // NEVER FALLS HERE BECAUSE userData IS ALWAYS NIL
 
            var userAccount: UserAccount?
            var errorMessage: ErrorMessage?
                
            if let _ = userData.userAccount.userId {
                userAccount = UserAccount(extractedFrom: userData)
            }
            if let _ = userData.error.code {
                errorMessage = ErrorMessage(extractedFrom: userData)
            }
                
            // Do some work with userData and delegates to presenter
            ....            
        }
    }
    
    // (2)
    private func doLoginInEndpoint(with user: User) -> UserData? {
        httpRequestWorker = LoginHTTPRequestWorker()
        return httpRequestWorker.doLogin(with: user)
    }
}
```

> #### **Class LoginHTTPRequestWorker**:

```
class LoginHTTPRequestWorker {
    private let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    // (3)
    func doLogin(with user: User) -> UserData? {
        var userData: UserData?
                
        makeRequest(with: user) { data in
            userData = data
            
            print(userData)
            self.group.leave()
        }
                    
        return userData
    }
    
    // (4)
    private func makeRequest(with user: User, completion: @escaping (UserData) -> ()) {
        let endpoint = // "a string representing an endpoint"
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [.contentType("application/json; charset=utf-8")]
         
        let request = AF.request(endpoint,
                                 method: .post,
                                 parameters: UserParameters(user: user.username, 
                                                            password: user.password),
                                 encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default,
                                 headers: headers)
        group.enter()
        
        request.responseDecodable(of: UserData.self) { response in
            self.group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                completion(response.value!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> #### **Struct UserParameters** (represents the parameters of the body POST request):

```
struct UserParameters: Encodable {
    let user: String
    let password: String
}
```

> #### **Struct UserData** (represents the data from JSON response):

```
struct UserData: Decodable {
    // some var declarations such as id, name etc
}
```

> #### **Enum Login** (represents the objects passed between ViewController, Interactor and Presenter):

```
enum Login {
    struct LoginFields {
        var username: String
        var password: String
    }
    
    enum Login {
        struct Request {
            var fields: LoginFields
        }
        
        struct Response {
            var user: UserAccount?
            var error: ErrorMessage?
        }
        
        struct ViewModel {
            var user: UserAccount?
            var error: ErrorMessage?
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to return an object after the POST request is over? Or is there a better way to do this task?
I searched around here, and found some solutions like: using DispatchGroup.wait(), DispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchMain), and using closures, but these solutions didn't work for me.

I apologize in advance as I am new to Swift and Stack Overflow but I would be very happy if someone could at least point me in a direction. Thanks!

Comment: You use correctly yourself `completion: @escaping (UserData) -> ()`, a asynchrone closure, why not doing that for `doLogin()`?

Comment: @Larme, thanks for answering, I really appreciate your atention. 
`doLogin()` is a public method, which is called from inside of `LoginInteractor`'s method `doLoginInEndpoint(with: user)`. I wish I could get the data by return of function, encapsulating the implementation. But I think your answer sounds good and I will try that.
Thanks!

Comment: @Larme, I cannot edit the comment above. 
I am here to thank you, your solution work properly! Thanks a lot!